# How to use Jupyter on EC2 WITHOUT Anaconda?

Tags: amazon-ec2, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

How do I run Jupyter notebook on EC2 without Anaconda or Enthought? I've looked at several instructions for running Jupyter on EC2 such as [[1]](http://blog.impiyush.me/2015/02/running-ipython-notebook-server-on-aws.html), [[2]](https://gist.github.com/iamatypeofwalrus/5183133), and [[3]](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-Jupyter-notebook-on-AWS), but all of them require installing Anaconda.

I've tried installing Jupyter normally (with `pip install jupyter`) and then running `jupyter notebook`, but it serves some kind of weird notebook into my terminal rather than with a webpage.

Comment: It's probably opening a text-based web browser in your terminal. You can avoid that with the `--no-browser` flag. See these instructions for setting it up with a password: http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public_server.html#running-a-public-notebook-server

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something by inspiring yourself from this blog article: 
[Install jupyter and python](http://argmin404.github.io/2016-04-28-Environment-Installation/)